# Convert list column to a string in place

Tags: r, string, list, data.table

Suppose I have a DT as -

```
           id                    disabled      total_capacity         name                  ts 
     1:  5922                                   5400,5400              xin        2020-10-28 20:00:00   
     2:  5922                                   5400,5400              xin        2020-10-28 21:00:00   
     3:  5922                                   5400,5400              xin        2020-10-28 22:00:00   
     4:  5922                                   5400,5400              xin        2020-10-28 19:00:00   
     5:  5922                                   5400,5400              xin        2020-10-28 18:00:00  
100087: 434701                    500,200       2200,2200,2200,2200    xin        2020-10-28 18:00:00 
100088: 434701                        200       2200,2200,2200,2200    xin        2020-10-28 21:00:00 
100089: 434701                        200       2200,2200,2200,2200    xin        2020-10-28 20:00:00 
100090: 434701                        200       2200,2200,2200,2200    xin        2020-10-28 19:00:00 
100091: 434701                        200       2200,2200,2200,2200    xin        2020-10-28 22:00:00
```

The columns `total_capacity`, `disabled` are lists.

```
> class(dt$total_capacity)
[1] "list"
```

I want to convert them to a string inplace for each row.

Expected output:

```
           id                    disabled      total_capacity         name                  ts 
     1:  5922                                   5400|5400              xin        2020-10-28 20:00:00   
     2:  5922                                   5400|5400              xin        2020-10-28 21:00:00   
     3:  5922                                   5400|5400              xin        2020-10-28 22:00:00   
     4:  5922                                   5400|5400              xin        2020-10-28 19:00:00   
     5:  5922                                   5400|5400              xin        2020-10-28 18:00:00  
100087: 434701                    500|200       2200|2200|2200|2200    xin        2020-10-28 18:00:00 
100088: 434701                        200       2200|2200|2200|2200    xin        2020-10-28 21:00:00 
100089: 434701                        200       2200|2200|2200|2200    xin        2020-10-28 20:00:00 
100090: 434701                        200       2200|2200|2200|2200    xin        2020-10-28 19:00:00 
100091: 434701                        200       2200|2200|2200|2200    xin        2020-10-28 22:00:00
```

I have tried -

```
dt[,total_capacity:=paste(total_capacity, collapse='|'),]
```

But this adds the entire column into one row entry.

How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use paste with `sapply`/`lapply` :

```
library(data.table)
dt[,total_capacity:= lapply(total_capacity,paste0, collapse = '|')]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Map`

```
library(data.table)
dt[, total_capacity := Map(paste0, MoreArgs = list(collapse= "|"), total_capacity)]
```

Comment: Are there any differences to using map vs lapply?

Comment: @leoOrion With `Map` you can have multiple arguments as well